# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. Rabbitmq

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rabbitmq, microservices

I have a NodeJS app. I'm using rabbitmq for connection between microservices. I get: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. When I send an HTTP request for the first time I get my data properly, but a second request causes this error. Why is this happening? Here is my users-service:

```
const connect = async () => {
    try {
        const amqpServer = "amqp://localhost:5672"
        connection = await amqp.connect(amqpServer)
        channel = await connection.createChannel()
        await channel.assertQueue(usersQueue)
        channel.consume(usersQueue, msg => {
            const token = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString()).token
            channel.ack(msg)
            if (token !== undefined && token !== null) {
                User.findOne({token: token}).exec((err, user) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return channel.sendToQueue(usersQueue, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(err)))
                    } else {
                        return channel.sendToQueue(usersQueue, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(user)))
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
connect()
```

Here is my history-service:

```
const connect = async () => {
    try {
        const amqpServer = "amqp://localhost:5672"
        connection = await amqp.connect(amqpServer)

        channel = await connection.createChannel()
        await channel.assertQueue(historyQueue)

        channel.consume(historyQueue, msg => {
            const audioId = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString()).audioId
            channel.ack(msg)
            if (audioId !== undefined && audioId !== null) {
                History.find({audio: audioId}).exec((err, history) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return channel.sendToQueue(historyQueue, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({err, status: false})))
                    } else {
                        return channel.sendToQueue(historyQueue, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({history, status: true})))
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
connect()
```

Here is my audios-service with api:

```
const connect = async () => {
    try {
        const amqpServer = "amqp://localhost:5672"
        connection = await amqp.connect(amqpServer)

        channel = await connection.createChannel()
        await channel.assertQueue(usersQueue)
        await channel.assertQueue(historyQueue)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
connect()
app.get("/get/analytics", (req, res) => {
    const token = {token: req.headers.token}
    if (req.headers.token !== undefined) {
        channel.sendToQueue(usersQueue, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(token)))
        channel.consume(usersQueue, userMsg => {
            const writer = JSON.parse(userMsg.content.toString())
            channel.ack(userMsg)
            if (writer._id != null) {
                Audio.findOne({_id: req.headers.id, writer: writer._id, status: 10}).exec((err, audio) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(400).send(err.message)
                    } else {
                        channel.sendToQueue(historyQueue, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({audioId: audio._id})))
                        channel.consume(historyQueue, historyMsg => {
                            channel.ack(historyMsg)
                            const history = JSON.parse(historyMsg.content.toString()).history
                            const noErr = JSON.parse(historyMsg.content.toString()).status
                            const errMessage = JSON.parse(historyMsg.content.toString()).err

                            if (noErr) {
                                res.status(200).json({audio, history})
                            } else {
                                res.status(500).json(errMessage)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            } else {
                return res.status(403).json("Token is false")
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: What exact request causes the error about headers? And, why are you showing three different sets of connect code?  What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: @jfriend00, these are three different files.

Comment: What rabbitMQ library are you using?  Please post a link to the module and to the documentation.

Comment: @jfriend00, get api request

Comment: Please read both of my questions again.  You didn't answer either of them.

Comment: @jfriend00, I've answered. "What exact request causes the error about headers?" = GET API request to "/get/analytics" endpoint causes this error. "And, why are you showing three different sets of connect code? " - because these are three different files, so each connect to rabbitmq is different. I mentioned rabbitmq because it might cause the issue.

Comment: Do all three connect pieces of code have their own `channel` variable?  Or are they all overwriting the same one?  And which `channel` variable is the `app.get("/get/analytics", ...)` route handler referring to.  I still have no idea why you're showing three separate piece of connect code.  Isn't only one of them being used by the route in question?  Or are all three somehow relevant to the route in question?

Comment: Also, can you please include a link to the module and documentation for the rabbitMQ library you're using?  I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib on my own (which is a guess for what you might be using), but its documentation links are busted.  I think I see a problem, but I need to confirm in the doc.

Comment: @jfriend00, yes they have their own channel variables. app.get() is express code. Yes, I use amqplib. The issue is that ```return res.status(200).json({audio, history})``` is called 2 times. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Based on some rabbitMQ documentation I found, it appears that a `channel.consume()` call sets up a consumer for messages on that channel and that consumer lasts as along as the channel does.  So, the first time your `/get/analytics` is hit, you set up a consumer for that channel and then the second time that route is hit, you set up ANOTHER consumer for that same channel, but the first one is still active.  So, when messages arrive on that channel, you will have duplicate consumers processing them and thus you will end up trying to send responses to old requests (from the original consumer that is still active) and thus the error message you get.

I don't really follow exactly what you're trying to do here, but you can either `.cancel()` the consumer after you're done with it so it won't be left around and still get future messages or you can remove the creation of the consumer from within your request handler so only one is ever created and somehow your request handler will get notified from the one consumer you have.

Note: This general structure looks to me like it would be subject to race conditions whenever there are more than one `/get/analytics` route handler in play at the same time since there's no way to discern which request that is in play should get which messages from the queue.

---

Also, note that when your condition:

```
 if (req.headers.token !== undefined) {
```

is not met, then you don't send any response to the request.  You should send some response to every request, probably want to send some 4xx status code, perhaps a 401 if the missing token means they aren't authorized.

---

To debug further, you can add some helpful logging:

```
const cntr = 0;
app.get("/get/analytics", (req, res) => {
    // log which request we're starting and keep a localCntr
    const localCntr = cntr++;
    console.log(`Start of request #${localCntr}`);

    const token = {token: req.headers.token}
    if (req.headers.token !== undefined) {
        channel.sendToQueue(usersQueue, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(token)))
        channel.consume(usersQueue, userMsg => {
            console.log(`${localCntr}: Getting channel.consume() callback on usersQueue`);
            const writer = JSON.parse(userMsg.content.toString())
            channel.ack(userMsg)
            if (writer._id != null) {
                Audio.findOne({_id: req.headers.id, writer: writer._id, status: 10}).exec((err, audio) => {
                    console.log(`${localCntr}: Got Audio.findOne() result`);
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(400).send(err.message)
                    } else {
                        channel.sendToQueue(historyQueue, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({audioId: audio._id})))
                        channel.consume(historyQueue, historyMsg => {
                            console.log(`${localCntr}: Getting channel.consume() callback on historyQueue`);
                            channel.ack(historyMsg)
                            const history = JSON.parse(historyMsg.content.toString()).history
                            const noErr = JSON.parse(historyMsg.content.toString()).status
                            const errMessage = JSON.parse(historyMsg.content.toString()).err

                            console.log(`${localCntr}: Sending response`);
                            if (noErr) {
                                res.status(200).json({audio, history})
                            } else {
                                res.status(500).json(errMessage)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            } else {
                return res.status(403).json("Token is false")
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, it's still isn't working. I use it like this - ```channel.consume(audioHistoryQueue, historyMsg => {channel.ack(historyMsg) channel.cancel(audioHistoryQueue)```

Comment: @DaniilAndreev - I don't know the API you're working with.  I asked for a link to the doc for whichever library you're using, but you didn't provide that so I can't really offer much more at this point.

Comment: I use amqplib. Here is a link to the docs - https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html

Comment: @DaniilAndreev - I've added a bunch of debugging logging to an example in my answer.  This logs exactly which callbacks you're getting and from which place and which request # they came from.  Those logs will probably tell you where the extra callbacks are coming from.  While inserting this logging, I see two separate calls to `channel.consume()`.  One is on the `historyQueue` and one on the `usersQueue`.  You would have to `.cancel()` both of those when you were done with a given request to avoid getting duplicate notifications of future events.

Comment: @DaniilAndreev - The key part of these debug messages is this `console.log(\`${localCntr}: Some other text \`);` which will tag each debug message with a sequence number that tells you which http request the debug message is from.  My  guess is that you see debug messages from old requests still occurring and that's what is causing the errors.

Comment: @DaniilAndreev - It appears that `channel.cancel()` needs a consumer tag, not the queue in order to work properly.  Please read the doc in detail for how that works.

Comment: How can I get a consumer tag?

Comment: @DaniilAndreev - Please read the doc for both `.consume()` and `.cancel()`.  It is explained there.

Comment: It's written in docs that consumer tag is string given in reply to consume, so it is queue. But it still doesn't help me

Comment: @DaniilAndreev - Why does that not help you.  The one example you showed me for `.cancel()` in your first comment here was NOT using a string given in reply to `.consume()`.  You were passing the queue itself to `.cancel()`.  That's not how it works.  Also, did you try the debugging I suggested to show where the extra responses are being sent from?

Comment: I debugged and It gives me "Some other text" one time. When I first time send get request to this route, it gives me all data perfectly, but when I send get request to this route second time, I get this error

Comment: I already send replyTo and cancel a channel using it, still isn't working.

Comment: It happens because of rabbitmq, because when I delete rabbitmq code, it doesn't give me this error.

Comment: Come on, if you run the code in my answer, you should be getting all sorts of logs that show all sorts of stuff.  Apparently you didn't run all that additional logging as shown in my answer.  I think I'm done here.  I'm making suggestions and asking questions and you just aren't helping me help you.

Comment: Yeah, of course, it's from the rabbitMQ code - there's nothing else really going on in this route handler without it.  The debugging as shown in my answer would contain the info needed to debug this problem.  But, after several hours have passed, you have not chosen to use it or share what it logged with several requests.  Nothing else I can do here.

Comment: I tried your debugging code. It gives me - ```Start of request #0
0: Getting channel.consume() callback on usersQueue
0: Got Audio.findOne() result
0: Getting channel.consume() callback on historyQueue
0: Sending response
```

Comment: Then I send second request. It gives me same output and then right after it it throws  this error. Here is the screenshot - https://imgur.com/a/J5Vd6sU

Comment: @DaniilAndreev - You can see from that screenshot that ALL the logs start with `0:`, even the ones that occur when the 2nd request starts.  That means those logs are all from the first request.  So, my theory is correct.  Your `.consume()` calls are stuck from the first request and they are feeding the original request, trying to send ANOTHER response leading to the error.  You have to either get the `.cancel()` to work or completely restructure how this code works so you don't create a new `.consume()` that lasts forever on your first request.

Comment: But cancel doesn't work. I use it like this - ```channel.cancel(historyMsg.properties.replyTo)```. And in history I send replyTo, which equals queue.

Comment: I fixed it. Without using cancel

Comment: @DaniilAndreev - OK, glad you fixed it without using cancel.  It's `consumerTag` you set on `.consume()` to set a tag to use with `.cancel()` so that is probably why `.cancel()` wasn't working for you.  How did you fix it?

Comment: I fixed it by creating and closing a new channel whenever someone hits the endpoint.

Comment: Sounds like a good way to go.  But, if those previous channels are still around, then you may be leaking memory on every request.